# Errors computing signals on Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to write in Matlab a script to create 3 signals, that have to be presented in the same graph (using plot). My code, in this moment, is

```
    n = 0:80;

    s = 2*n*(0.9).^n;      %signal 1 (can be a real or an imaginary signal)
    r = rand(1, 81) - 0.5; %signal 2 (can be a real or an imaginary signal)

    x = s + r;             %signal 3: it is supposed to be the sum of the other 2 signals
    xr = real(x);
    xi = imag(x);
    x = xe + xi;

   ER = XXX_A_B(x, s);

   plot(n, s, n, r, n, x, n, ER); %plot
   title('s[n], r[n], x[n], ER) %ER: Error related to the approximation of x to s
   legend('s[n]', 'r[n]','x[n]', 'ER')
```

I had already done a function to compute ER, so I used it to calculate it now. The function is

```
   function [ER] = XXX_A_B(x1, x2)
      x = abs(x2-x1);
      L2 = norm(x, 2);
      L2_1 = norm(x1, 2);
      ER = L2/L2_1;
   end
```

It happens that already in the first line, it appears an error (not saying of what kind) and another on x = s + r. I'm not understanding the reason of these mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Check the `size` of everything. I suspect `s` is not the shape you expect it to be.

Comment: Also, `xe` is undefined. Did you mean for it to be `x = xr + xi`? In which case, that line is pointless. `x` is already equal to `xr + xi`.

Comment: Finally, I find it slightly unbelievable that Matlab won't tell you what the error is. Are you sure something isn't suppressing the error? Try running the offending lines in the Matlab console and see what error you get

Comment: Thanks @PranavHosangadi . When I run the first two lines, what appears is just "Related documentation"

Comment: It's working!! Thanks! @PranavHosangadi

Comment: Great! Pro tip: [use Matlab's inbuilt debugger to step through your code and make sure everything is the way you expect it!](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) This is a crucial skill when you're writing programs of any kind. This article on [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is also very enlightening

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that the matrix dimensions cause errors. Depending on your intended function matrix multiplication by taking the transpose or element-wise multiplication might fix the first issue. Another issue is `xe` is not defined before using it as the comment above outlines.

```
n = 0:80; %1 by 81 array%

    Part_Of_Equation = (0.9).^n; %1 by 81 array%   
    
    %Taking transpose of n -> n.' (matrix multiplication)%
    s = 2*n.'*Part_Of_Equation;   
    
    %Or multipling element-wise%
    s = 2*n.*Part_Of_Equation;
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: It was the second case. I got it! Thanks!! @MichaelTr7